# The event addUserSignedOut is triggered automaticity only when i use IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, openid-connect

I'm using oidc.js version:1.5.2 with aspnet webforms and for some reason when I navigate to my callback page, someone is triggering my addUserSignedOut event.
This strange behavior happens only in IE11 (in chrome,edge,firefox it works fine).

**This is the Main page**

```
        var baseUrl = top.location.protocol + '//' + top.location.host;

        var config = {
            authority: "http://...",
            client_id: 'xyz',
            redirect_uri: baseUrl + '/myFolder/callback.html?',
            post_logout_redirect_uri: baseUrl + '/myFolder/page.html?',
            revokeAccessTokenOnSignout: true,
            response_type: 'id_token token',
            scope: 'abc',
            prompt: 'true',
            loadUserInfo: true,
            automaticSilentRenew: true,
            accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 1800,
        };

       var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);

        var isLoggedIn = function () {
            return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                mgr.getUser()
                    .then(function (token) {
                        console.log("getUser token=" + token);
                        resolve(token != null);
                    });
            });
        }

        var doLogin = function () {
            this.isLoggedIn().then(function (res) {
                if (!res)
                    mgr.signinRedirect();
            });
        };

        var doLogout = function () {
            mgr.signoutRedirect();
        };

        var registerEvents = function () {
            this.isLoggedIn().then(function (res) {

                if (res) {
                    mgr.events.addUserSignedOut(function () {

                        Auth.userManager.removeUser();

                        return Auth.userManager.signoutRedirect();
                    });
                }
            });
        };

        registerEvents();


    </script>
```

This is callback page

```
<script>
    new Oidc.UserManager({ response_mode: "query" }).signinRedirectCallback().then(function (res) {
        if (res) {
            console.log("token = " + res.access_token);
            window.location.href = "page.html";
            }
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.error(e);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show your code? without it we can only guess what may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Of course. i added the code (above).

Comment: First you have error in your code look at highlighting, almost all is marked as string, because you didn't closed one in `scope: 'sast_api openid`, but this is probably typo because you had API key there.

Comment: The problem I see, not sure how this would be different on different browser. Check what res is (inside isLoggedIn promise) maybe it's different object in IE and in other browser. Add `console.log(res)` or `console.dir(res)`. and check in IE and modern browser.

Comment: any chance your callback page code execute even not on load page, can you try to add the script to `onload` function or inside `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { })`

Comment: i have try to add document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { }) on callback page, but still someone triggering my addUserSignedOut event.

Comment: by the way, when i try to insert:                                                       
window.setTimeOut(mgr.events.addUserSignedOut (function () {},2000))                  its works but still this is no a good solution for my app so i need a better solution.

Comment: Try to add some debugger and use [F12 developer tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255007(v%3dvs.85)) to trace the process, and check where trigger this function.

Comment: I have try it already.its came from the library of oidc-client api. the question is if oidc.js support Properly in IE11.

Comment: Wait, you're calling `registerEvents` function that call `isLoggedIn` and then log user out, why are you calling this function? This should be the same on every browser though.

Comment: I don't see the problem of it. if i removed isLoggedIn method still someone triggering addUserSignedOut event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the issue is related to IE security zones, you could try to go into Internet Options > Security and uncheck the "Enabled Protected Mode" for the "Internet" zone.

Comment: Thanks. can you explain me why is this issue happens only in aspnet web forms and not for example in kind of spa architecture?

Comment: do you know maybe how can i solve this problem without changing IE security zones?